# Jquery Triggers Not Working After Ajax Calling

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have 2 pages of PHP, "**booking.php**" and "**fetch_book_time.php**".

> Inside my **booking.php** (where the jquery trigger is)

```
<?php
    include ("conn.php");
    include ("functions.php");
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".form-group").on("change", ".ajax-venue", function(){
        $(".ajax-date").trigger("change"); // if .ajax-venue is changed,
    });                                    // then trigger change on .ajax-date

    $(".form-group").on("change", ".ajax-date", function(){
        // var getData = all my data here

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "fetch_book_time.php",
            data: getData,
            cache: false,
            success: function(getTime){
                $("#ajax-time").html(getTime);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    Venue: <br>
    <select id='ajax-venue' class="ajax-venue">
        <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM slot");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option value='".$row['slot_venue']."'>".$row['slot_venue']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    Date: <br>
    <input id="ajax-date" type="date" class="ajax-date"></input>
</div>
<div id="ajax-time" class="form-group">
    Start Time:<br>
    <input id="ajax-sTime" class="ajax-sTime" type="time"></input><br>
    End Time:<br>
    <input id="ajax-eTime" class="ajax-eTime" type="time"></input>
</div>
```

> inside my **fetch_book_time.php** (ajax page)

```
<?php
    include ("conn.php");
    include ("functions.php");

    // code and logic here then echo back the codes below

    // input sent back to booking.php into #ajax-time
?>
```

After cranking up my head for hours, I finally found out that the problem lies in my **include** files in **fetch_book_time.php**.

If I removed the **include** files from **fetch_book_time.php** the Jquery triggers can work  as what I wanted, which is to trigger a change on the date input every time the venue has been changed.

Any solution or help would be much appreciated as I am still very new to Jquery and hope to have a progress in this project. Thank you.

Comment: If removing those includes makes it work, then the logical conlusion is that they caused some sort of error, which makes your AJAX part not receive a 200 OK status code any more. Check what your error log has to say, and check how the request got answered in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: And FYI, `$("#ajax-time").html(getTime);` inside your success callback would now insert a new element with the ID `ajax-time`, into the already existing element with that same ID. IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document - so you should _replace_ the existing element with the new content here, rather than appending it. (Or have the PHP script return only the HTML that is supposed to go _inside_ that element to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe Ahh I'm sorry, the <div id="ajax-time"> won't be called out. I added there for reference purposed but failed to realize that it is a mistake putting there. As for the 200 OK status. I have checked on it and there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

because you are adding new htmls to page, so you have to bind your events after each

```
success: function(getTime){
                $("#ajax-time").html(getTime);
            }
```

or simply define your events globally on document:

so change

```
 $(".form-group").on("change", ".ajax-venue", function(){
```

to :

```
$(document).on("change", ".form-group.ajax-venue", function(){
```

and

```
$(".form-group").on("change", ".ajax-date", function(){
```

to :

```
$(document).on("change", ".form-group.ajax-date", function(){
```

Comment: I have just tried it out, but unfortunately the Jquery won't run at all.

Comment: Why? What is the error?

Comment: Probably the events are not registered, when the value is changed nothing happened.

Comment: `$(document).on("change", ".form-group.ajax-date", function(){` is not the same as `$(".form-group").on("change", ".ajax-date", function(){`  in the second (non-document), .ajax-date must be a descendent of .form-group, but you've made it so the element has to have both classes.  Needs a space

Comment: Ahh thank you @freedomn-m I have added on a space ```$(document).on("change", ".form-group .ajax-date", function(){``` but it still didn't solve the problem I am facing with.